# cuda - How does nvcc compile __host__ code?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to convert my c++ only project to cuda code to run on GPU.

I'm new to cuda programming and I don't know what to do with this circumstance:

If I have a very complicated class definition and now I want to pass a class instance to the device and execute some of its member functions on the device, I then should rewrite my whole `.cpp` file. Do I only need to turn those functions run on device to `__host__ __device__` or should I rewrite all the functions?

I think `nvcc` treat functions with no function type qualifiers as `__host__`. How does it compile host code? Does it compile them exactly as `g++` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I have a very complicated class definition and now I want to pass a
>   class instance to the device and execute some of its member functions
>   on the device, I then should rewrite my whole .cpp file. Do I only
>   need to turn those functions run on device to `__host__ __device__` or
>   should I rewrite all the functions?

That depends entirely on your code. CUDA has support for a limited subset of C++ language features (fully documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-cplusplus-language-support)) and almost no C++ standard library is supported. So there is no general answer, but it is likely that you will have to rewrite at least some of your class member function code if you wish to call them on the GPU.

> I think nvcc treat functions with no function type qualifiers as `__host__`. How does it compile host code? Does it compile them exactly as g++ does?

The first thing to understand is that nvcc isn't a compiler, it is a *compiler driver*. Plain C++ code in a file without a .cu file extension is, by default, passed straight to the host compiler with a set of predefined compiler options without modification.

Host code inside a .cu extension file is parsed by the CUDA C++ front end to look for CUDA syntax and then passed to the host compiler. This process can fail on extremely complex template definitions and bleeding edge language features. nvcc also includes CUDA headers automatically and these headers can potentially conflict with the contents of your own code. But eventually your host code reaches the host C++ compiler, albeit by a different route.